# StackOverFlowError in XSLT Transformation

Tags: java

I am trying to transform an xml file using a com.queplix.core.utils.xml.TransletWrapper class which is providd by QueWeb Framework.I am getting StackOverFlowError in the below code @line  transletWrapper.transform(source, new StreamResult(out), transletName, transletParams);

any help will be appreciated.. Tanks!

```
char[] data = XMLHelper.writeObject(report);

// Do XSLT.
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new CharArrayReader(data));
CharArrayWriter out = new CharArrayWriter(data.length);

try {
   transletWrapper.transform(source, new StreamResult(out), transletName, transletParams);
    } catch (GenericSystemException ex) {
       throw new GenericSystemException("Cannot transform source: \n", ex);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the full exception stacktrace and (part of) the XML you're trying to transform ?

Comment: That line doesn't look wrong to me. I would guess that the problem lies in your xslt code.

Comment: javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.io.CharArrayWriter.write(CharArrayWriter.java:79)
  at org.apache.xml.serializer.ToStream.processDirty(ToStream.java:1531)
  at org.apache.xml.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1449)
  at org.apache.xml.serializer.ToHTMLStream.characters(ToHTMLStream.java:1516)
  at org.apache.xpath.objects.XString.dispatchCharactersEvents(XString.java:204)
  at org.apache.xpath.Expression.executeCharsToContentHandler(Expression.java:313)
  at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemValueOf.execute(ElemValueOf.java:272)

Comment: This is the text whixh i want to transform and each time a different text is generated for transformation <, ?, x, m, l,  , v, e, r, s, i, o, n, =, ", 1, ., 0, ",  , e, n, c, o, d, i, n, g, =, ", U, T, F, -, 8, ", ?, >, 
, <, r, e, p, o, r, t,  , p, r, o, c, e, s, s, I, d, =, ", 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7, 8, 1, 4, 2, ",  , p, r, i, n, t, P, a, g, e, =, ", f, a, l, s, e, ",  , i, g, n, o, r, e, I, n, c, l, u, d, e, T, o, R, e, p, o, r, t, =, ", f, a, l, s, e, ", >, <, r, e, q, s,  , p, a, g, e, =, ", 0, ",  , p, a, g, e, s, i, z, e, =, ", -, 1, ",  , d, o, c, o, u, n, t, =, ", f, a,

Comment: Can someone please help me. I have posted the xml n the full stacktrace also.